# Alternative names for a value that can either be true or false?

Tags: types, keywords

I know most languages use 'bool' or 'boolean' but I do not really like that name seeing as it was named after a person and a highly doubt that person invented the idea of yes or no questions altogether.

So what are some other good names for a datatype in a language that can either be `true` or `false`?

Comment: Well, George Boole did come up with boolean logic, so in a way he did invent (computational) yes or no questions...

Comment: Binary? Logical Atom? Affirmation Atom?

Comment: Are you designing a language for your own enjoyment, or to meet the needs of a developer constituency? If the former, pick whatever makes you happy personally. If the latter, **ask them**.

Comment: Often, users will want a domain-specific yes/no value, so not yes/no at all but like overwrite/insert or with serif/without serif...

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned yet is **bit**, as it is in SQL.

I don't see a problem with *Boolean* or *bool*, though. It's a widely-known, highly-specific, and vocally-succinct word for one of the most common data types.

I don't think any of the alternatives on display so far are more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Binary value
2. Two-state value
3. Truth value
4. Logical value
5. Propositional value
6. Logical value
7. Yes/no value
8. True/false value

Comment: Truth atom is the best

Answer (score 0):

1. Binary value
2. Truth atom
3. Biaxiological atom
4. Binary Axiological Atom
5. Biaxiological Value
6. Bilogical value
7. Logical atom